# Spresense LTE 拡張ボードで、1リクエストごとの通信量に制限は存在する？

Tags: spresense

Spresense LTE拡張ボードについて質問です。

Arduino IDEの開発環境でバイナリデータをHTTP POSTしたところ、ファイルサイズが4キロ・5キロバイトで以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
up_assert: Assertion failed at file:irq/irq_unexpectedisr.c line: 51 task: Idle Task
```

LTE拡張ボードは1リクエストごとの通信量に制限等ありますか？

Answer (score 0):

ファイルサイズが4キロ未満なら問題ないのでしょうか？

挙げているAsserionは例外割り込みエラーなので、例えばプログラムがハングアップしたなどでのwatchdogタイマーの発生（使っているならばの話）や領域オーバーなどによるプログラム破壊などが疑われます。

アドバイスもらうには情報が足りていないので、プログラムやAssertionのダンプなどを含めて情報を記載した方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

この質問はSony製のLTE-M拡張ボードに関する質問を想定しています。Sakura.ioのLTE拡張ボードもあります。

MQTTで>200KBの画像を送ろうとした時に１回mqttClient.write()当たりの制限があることがわかりました。したがって、データを複数のwrite()で分割する必要がありました。
おそらく以下のconfigと関係があります。

```
CONFIG_CXD56_DMAC_SPI4_TX_MAXSIZE=2064
CONFIG_CXD56_DMAC_SPI4_RX_MAXSIZE=2064
```

MQTTだけではなく、HTTP POSTにも適用されます。
Arduino SDKのリコンパイルすれば、上げることができます。

但し、制限を超えても、クラッシュはありません。Assertionは他の理由があると思います。